# Regular expressions in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a simple query. I am new to regular expression validations in C#.

I want some expression which would allow only single alphabet that means a-z or A-Z. It should not allow whole word. Can anyone suggest me an expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

This expression allows one or more characters in the specified range. And if you want only a single character:

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

Comment: Please realize that these expressions also matches the comma as it is included between the square brackets…

Comment: @mousio, thanks for pointing this out, I've updated my answer to fix this.

Comment: @mousio sorry bt i did not get your point. did you mean that it will allow that is accept the comma alongwith the single character???????

Comment: A "character class" (or "character set") matches only one out of several characters, just place the characters you want to match in square brackets. **A character class matches only a single character.** `gr[ae]y` will not match `graay`, `graey` or any such thing. Use a hyphen to specify a range: `[0-9]` matches a single digit between 0 and 9. You can use more than one range: `[a-zA-Z]` matches a single letter, case insensitively. You can combine ranges and single characters. `[a-z,A-Z]` matches a lowercase or uppercase letter or the comma. The order of characters and ranges does not matter.

Comment: More information on [character classes in this part](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) of [regular-expressions.info's tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).